# Haskell design best practice for multiple modules assocated with similar set of functions

Tags: java, design-patterns, haskell, interface, typeclass

Say the functions `foo`, `bar` `noo` are the basics in my program. Furthermore, these functions can be implemented in different way in different *scenarios* (`foo1, bar1`,  `foo2, bar2`, etc), though `foo1` and `foo2` still have the same input and output types.  According to some input or configuration, the program use `foo1, bar1` in some *scenario*, while in another *scenario*, `foo2, bar2`.

I could have just defined them as described above, appending suffix (1,2,3..) to `foo, bar, noo`. However, this is not pretty as the suffix could be long; neither does it allow special binding of `foo1` with `bar1` (vs. `bar2`).

An alternative would be treating each *scenario* as a separate `Module`. Now `foo, bar, noo` for each case are nicely hold together, and the ugly suffix is avoided. However, this introduces many files when having one file per `Module`. Another downside of this approach is that these `Modules` are completed separated even though they do share some similarity (e.g. three functions).

A `typeclass` solution would be appreciated but not came across my mind, as the different `foo`s of different *scenarios* have the same input and output.

I am wondering is there any Haskell best practice for the problem to avoid the aforementioned shortcomings of these approaches.

```
foo1 :: Double -> Double
bar1 :: Int -> Int
noo1 :: [Int] -> [Int]

foo2 :: Double -> Double
bar2 :: Int -> Int
noo2 :: [Int] -> [Int]

...

foo9 :: Double -> Double
bar9 :: Int -> Int
noo9 :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

**EDIT**: I guess it is relevant for the discussion to explain how  I would approach it through `Java Interface` (A few nice, but conceptual-level,  discussion of `Java interface` and `Haskell typeclass` can be found at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948166/javas-interface-and-haskells-type-class-differences-and-similarities) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122109/difference-between-oop-interfaces-and-fp-type-classes).) `Java interface and class` can be complicated for many cases, but here the overloading is actually concise.

```
interface Scenario {
  double     foo(double d);
  int        bar(int i);
  Array<int> noo(Array<int> a);
}

class UseScenario {
  void use(Scenario ss) {
    ss.foo(...);
    ss.bar(...);
    ss.noo(...);
  }
}

class S1 implements Scenario {
  double     foo(double d) {...};
  int        bar(int i) {...};
  Array<int> noo(Array<int> a) {...};
}

class S2 implements Scenario {
  double     foo(double d) {...};
  int        bar(int i) {...};
  Array<int> noo(Array<int> a) {...};
}
```

Comment: At this level of generality you're pretty much correct, you could use different names, different modules, or typeclasses. Without knowing the application in more detail it's hard to say which is best.

Comment: What do you mean by *scenario*? You might want to look at the [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.2.1) library which has separate modules for lazy and strict maps. I'm sure there's some code shared between the two. I agree with tel; try making your question more specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One good way would be to put all the functions into a single data type. Then have different values of that type for each different strategy. Finally, choose a default strategy, and link the actual functions tho the default strategy (for ease of use). Eg:

```
module MyModule where


data Strategy  = Strategy {
    fooWithStrategy :: Double -> Double
  , barWithStrategy :: Int -> Int
  , nooWithStrategy :: [Int] -> [Int]
  }

defaultStrategy :: Strategy
defaultStrategy = Strategy { 
    fooWithStrategy = (*2)
  , barWithStrategy = (+2)
  , nooWithStrategy = id
  }

foo :: Double -> Double
foo = fooWithStrategy defaultStrategy

bar :: Int -> Int
bar = barWithStrategy defaultStrategy

noo :: [Int] -> [Int]
noo = nooWithStrategy defaultStrategy

tripleStrategy :: Strategy
tripleStrategy = Strategy {
    fooWithStrategy = (*3)
  , barWithStrategy = (*3)
  , nooWithStrategy = \x -> x ++ x ++ x
  }

customAddStrategy :: Int -> Strategy
customAddStrategy n = Strategy {
    fooWithStrategy = (+ (fromIntegral n))
  , barWithStrategy = (+ n)
  , nooWithStrategy = (n :)
  }
```

This allows a number of useful features:

1. Customizable strategies (eg the `customAddStrategy`). You could also mix and match strategies, eg `newStrat = defaultStrategy { nooWithStrategy = nooWithStrategy tripleStrategy, fooWithStrategy = (*4) }`
2. Users can switch strategies at run time
3. Defaults (ie `foo`, `bar` and `noo`) are available for users new to the library
4. Easily extended with more strategies by you or other users.

Comment: `data` type declaration can have records of functions due to function being first class citizen? So I don't even need to bother `typeclass`.

Comment: @Causality: That is right, you only need type classes when the type of the function needs to change (eg `show` can have the type `Int -> String` and `Bool -> String`). While you could probably build a solution for your problem using type classes (eg using a phantom type to specify the instance to use), just using a data type with functions inside is much simpler and better. See [haskell antipattern: existential typeclass](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) for another example where using a data type is much simpler than using a typeclass.

Comment: what if `foo, bar, noon` can not be implemented in a pointfree style? i.e. the input need to be explicitly expressed: `foo x = ...`, `bar y = ...`, `noon z = ...`. This lead to compilation error: `parse error on input 'x'`

Comment: @Causality: You can use lambda (`nooWithStrategy = \n -> ...`) or write a local function in a `where` clause (`nooWithStrategy = foo } where foo n = ...`).