# Scala Generic List addition

Tags: scala, implicit, subtyping

I have function:

```
 def listSum[T](xs :List[T])(implicit  abc : Numeric[T]): T = {
    xs.sum
  }

  val IntList: List[Int] = List (1, 2, 3, 4)
  val DList: List[Double] = List (1.0, 2.0, 3, 4)
```

the code example above works fine, but when I change to the function below it stops working with error

> could not find implicit value for parameter `abc: Numeric[AnyVal]`

Since `AnyVal` is the base type I can do the addition, can't I ?

where are all the implicits defined?

```
 def listSum(xs :List[AnyVal])(implicit  abc : Numeric[AnyVal]) = {
    xs.sum
  }

 val AList: List[AnyVal] = List (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Also this is not working , I think for the same reason .

```
  def listSum[T](xs :List[T])(implicit  abc : Numeric[T]): T = {
    xs.sum
  }

  val BList : List[Boolean] = List(true, false)
  println(listSum(BList))
```

Comment: You can't sum "anyval", as it isn't defined how to do it. You can however sum "numeric" things. Example `def listSum[T: Numeric](xs: List[T]): T = xs.sum`

Answer (score 3):

There are several incorrent assumptions in your question:

1. [`AnyVal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyVal.html) is the supertype of all primitive types and [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). Along with [`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html) it's one of two type branches, rooted in the [`Any`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html) type, which is true supertype of all.
2. [`Numeric`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) type is not [covariant](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html) which means that existence of `Numeric[Int]` does not imply existence of `Numeric[AnyVal]`, which is very logical, if you think for a second. Integer numbers is subdomain of Real numbers, but knowing how to multiply integers does not mean you know how to multiply reals.
3. [Subtyping polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) [is not directly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948166/javas-interface-and-haskells-type-class-differences-and-similarities) to [restricted parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Bounded_parametric_polymorphism). First is mostly handled runtime while second is generally for compile-time. They interact in very specific ways in scala.
4. There is no single place where implicit values are defined. [There are multiple places](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html) for each specific type and place in code.

Answer (score 2):

## All the implicit definitions for Numeric[T] are defined in scala/math/Numeric.scala

(assuming scala 2.10.4)

There is no implicit definition for `Numeric[AnyVal]`, so this is why you get the error for your first example (this makes sense, because one cannot define numeric operations without knowing anything about the underlying type)

There is also no implicit definition for `Numeric[Boolean]`, which is why you get the error for your second example (this also makes sense, because one cannot define the `plus`, `minus`, `times`, `negate`, etc. operation on Booleans without assuming anything about the specific domain of the project).

you can define an implicit `Numeric[Boolean]` yourself if that makes sense for your project, but it would be better to avoid using the implicit Numeric[T] for the Boolean type.